# placing all data from list into seperate tkinter label

Tags: python, list, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a function, where it prints rows and columns of a string from a list.

```
input_data_col1 = [row1,row2,row3]
input_data_col2 = [row1,row2,row3]
input_data_col3 = [row1,row2,row3]
input_data_col4 = [row1,row2,row3]
```

Desired output: (in gridded tkinter label)

```
row1    row1    row1    row1
row2    row2    row2    row2
row3    row3    row3    row3
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at, [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on  how to arrange widgets in a grid, and there are questions on this site that show how to create tables. It's not clear what specific help you need. Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(ina, inb, inc, ind):
  print('\n'.join('    '.join(['{:.4f}'.format(x) for x in l]) for l in [ina, inb, inc, ind]))
```

This is a very naive approach that won’t work in practice. In reality, you should be storing these in a data table. Look into the `pandas.DataFrame` object’s documentation.

For a brief example, consider an array:

```
data = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]
```

You can create a pandas data table from this data using

```
pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

You can add row labels as so:

```
labels = [“a”, “b”, “c”, “d”]
pandas.DataFrame(data, labels)
```

There are many other things you can do with the pandas library, this is why I strongly suggest reading its documentation.

**The OP changed their question afterwards, so here is my updated answer**

You could create a table of labels, then pad each to a unique cell, for example

```
def func(data):
  labels = [[Label(root, text = cell) for cell in y] for y in data]
  for i in range(len(labels)):
    for j in range(len(labels[i])):
      labels[i][j].grid(i, j)
```

Comment: Interesting thanks. I'll have a read of it. How would I go about gridding the data in a 4x4 grid into Labels with tkinter?

Comment: thanks, it worked, but i couldn't get panda to install on my mac, so i to do this on my PC. Had to resort to some non-module method, but useful information, for some of future projects, thanks again

Comment: No problem. Just next time, try to emphasize more on your original question, and be specific.